# neo4j cypher - Differing query plan behavior

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Nodes with the `Location` node label have an index on `Label.name`

Profiling the following query gives me a smart plan, with a `NodeHashJoin` between the two sides of the graph on either side of `Trip` nodes. Very clever. Works great.

```
PROFILE MATCH (rosen:Location)<-[:OCCURS_AT]-(ev:Event)<-[:HAS]-(trip:Trip)-[:OPERATES_ON]->(date:Date)
WHERE rosen.name STARTS WITH "U Rosent" AND
      ev.scheduled_departure_time > "07:45:00" AND
      date.date = '2015-11-20'

RETURN rosen.name, ev.scheduled_departure_time, trip.headsign
ORDER BY ev.scheduled_departure_time
LIMIT 20;
```

[image: Plan with NodeHashJoin]

However, just changing one line of the query from:

```
WHERE rosen.name STARTS WITH "U Rosent" AND
```

to

```
WHERE id(rosen) = 4752371 AND
```

seems to alter the entire behavior of the query plan, which now appears to become more "sequential", losing the parallel execution of `(Trip)-[:OPERATES_ON]->(Date)`

[image: Linear plan]

Much slower. 6x more DB hits in total.

**Question**

**Why does changing the retrieval of one, seemingly-unrelated `Location` node via a different index/mechanism alter the behavior of the whole query?**

(I'm not sure how best to convey more information about the graph model, but please advise, and I'd be happy to add details that are missing)

**Edit:**

It gets better. Changing that query line from:

```
WHERE rosen.name STARTS WITH "U Rosent" AND
```

to

```
WHERE rosen.name = "U Rosenthaler Platz." AND
```

results in the same loss of parallelism in the query plan!

Seems odd that a `LIKE` query is faster than an  `=` ?